# Using AsyncTask for sleeping

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to use the AsyncTask to create a splash screen. Specifically, in the doInBackground() method I use the static method Thread.sleep() and after it's created an intent which redirects the app to the other activity. I don't get any errors, but the app didn't change the activity. My code is:

```
/***This class redirects the user to the 'MainActivity'. ***/
class RedirectToMainActivityTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        try 
        {
            Thread.sleep( 2 * 1000 );
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException e )
        {
            Log.e( "MAINACTIVITY-ERROR", e.getMessage());
            showTheError( "Error while starting MainActivity: " + e.getMessage() );
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class );
        intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
        startActivity( intent );

        finish();           
        return null;
    }       
}
```

Comment: hey if my answer helped you out, please mark it as right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure you added the activity in your manifest

```
 <activity android:name="com.example.listissue.SecondActivity"/>
```

also don't call to finish()

```
private class RedirectToMainActivityTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        try 
        {
            Thread.sleep( 2 * 1000 );
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    } 

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
          Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class );
          intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
          startActivity( intent );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to do it with a handler? :

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

        Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class );
        intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
        startActivity( intent )
            }
        }, 2000);   //time you want to wait until MainActivity start
```

Comment: You're using an application context, so you'll also have to add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to place the below code in OnPostExecute() method

```
    Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class );
    intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
    startActivity( intent );
```